# How to deconstruct a compound term in SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog, destructuring

I have compound terms that can have a  number inside the braces.

For example: `qpowieipq(5),lsjdlasa(15)` or `lkjlk`. I got it from the database (like `my_list([rxclk,rxer,rxdv,rxd(0),rxd(1),rxd(2),crs,col,txen,txd(0),txd(1),txd(2),‌​txd(3)]).`).

How can I get the value of the number inside the braces?

For example:

```
my_function(qpowieipq(5), X).
X=5.
my_function(lsjdlasa(15), X).
X=15.
my_function(lkjlk, X).
false
```

I am using SWI Prolog.

Comment: your description is missing key details required to answer... what is 'database': SQL ? what is 'string': atom ? which Prolog are you using ?

Comment: 1. database: for examle: 
my_list([rxclk,rxer,rxdv,rxd(0),rxd(1),rxd(2),crs,col,txen,txd(0),txd(1),txd(2),txd(3)]).  

2. SWI-Prolog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [(=..)/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D..%29/2) and pattern matching to deconstruct Prolog's compound terms. For instance

```
?- a =.. X.
X = [a].

?- a(1) =.. X.
X = [a, 1].
```

So, tentatively

```
my_function(T, V) :- T =.. [_,V], number(V).
```

This will work with any ISO compliant Prolog processor.